# How do I write html code inside jquery?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, search, font-awesome, sidebar

I have a search bar showing on my wordpress site and have used jquery to replace the "search" word and want to use an icon from font awesome. However it just displays the font awesome code, not the icon.

How do I go about replacing the submit button text with a font awesome icon?

I cant seem to edit the "value" as this is in a sidebar. This is what I have so far...

```
<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" class="searchform" action="http://localhost/">
                <div>
                    <label class="screen-reader-text" for="s">Search for:</label>
                    <input type="text" value="" name="s" id="s">
                    <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search"></input>
                </div>
            </form>


<script type="text/javascript">
    var $elem = $("#searchsubmit");
    $elem.html("<i class='fa fa-eye'></i>");
</script>
```

Comment: If you want to change all HTML content of an element using jQuery, just use this method [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

Make sure to select the element using jQuery first: $(elem).html(...)

Comment: @Hp93 is almost correct in their comment above, but `input` elements have no HTML content. That only works with a `button`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The submit button has to be a `<button>` and not an `<input type="button"`as inputs can't have HTML content, but `button` elements can.

Note: A side effect of `input` element styling is that applying FA classes directly to them *does not work*. The icon is only visible on inline elements such as a `span` or `i` (which FA recommend).

Set the HTML instead:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var $elem = $("#searchsubmit");
    $elem.html("<i class='fa fa-eye'></i>");
</script>
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/JfGVE/907/

Update with the OPs own HTML (corrected to have `button` type): http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/JfGVE/909/

e.g.

```
<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" class="searchform" action="http://localhost/">
  <div>
    <label class="screen-reader-text" for="s">Search for:</label>
    <input type="text" value="" name="s" id="s">
    <button type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search"></button>
  </div>
</form>
```

If you cannot control the source code, you can add the button dynamically instead and replace the original.

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/JfGVE/911/

```
var $elem = $("#searchsubmit");
$elem.replaceWith('<button type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></button>');
```

or just

```
$("#searchsubmit").replaceWith('<button type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></button>');
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/JfGVE/912/

Comment: I didn't downvote your answer, however when I use your code the "search" text on the submit button is not replaced with anything anymore, the word "search" re appears. The code I originally posted in the question replaced it, but just didn't show the icon, only the icon code - <i class='fa fa-eye'></i>

Comment: @5kud: please show the rest of the code and HTML. I will put up a quick demo showing this will work with the assumptions made about your HTML :) JSFiddle Added: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/JfGVE/907/

Comment: full code for that page is now in the question, thanks

Comment: @5kud: please provide the output DOM/HTML, not the source... there is no `id=searchsubmit` element in your code :)

Comment: @5kud: Now please read my comment that it cannot be an `input` element and must be a `button` as inputs don't have content! :)

Comment: @5kud: Your HTML working (with correction to button type). http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/JfGVE/909/

Comment: thanks! however I've been searching through my wordpress files and cant find where the form actually is to change the input type, any ideas? I'm using naked wordpress theme

Comment: @5kud: If you cannot find it in the site source, you can always change/add the button using jQuery. I have updated the answer to do that as well.

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you need is to change the style of the `element`. e.g.

```
document.getElementById("searchsubmit").className = "fa fa-eye"
```

Comment: Or the "use jQuery" version, `$("#searchsubmit").addClass("fa fa-eye")`

Comment: I think your comment about `i` element is completely wrong. Just try and see it.

Comment: well, who knows if #searchsubmit is indeed an <i> ! :)

Comment: @liusy182: "the submit button text" in the question kind of gives it away :P

Comment: Font awesome needs an I element to work, I'm afraid this isn't going to work

Comment: @others: Font awesome is a font, and it doesn't need `i` tag to work with. here a simple [example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RrVZjv). Inspect the icon code to see the real work behind it and you will understand. Hint: see ::before

Comment: Just for the record, this solution will not work on an input element: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/JfGVE/914

Answer (score 0):

If the submit button is a `<button>` and not an `<input>` then you can use the following code:

```
var elem = document.getElementById("searchsubmit");
elem.innerHTML = "<i class='fa fa-eye'></i>";
```

However, if you don't have an event listener on DOM load, then you should probably wrap your code in a self-executing function and put it at the end of your HTML.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function(){
    var elem = document.getElementById("searchsubmit");
    elem.innerHTML = "<i class='fa fa-eye'></i>";
})();
</script>
```

**Update:** This way, you will be limiting the scope of the variable called `elem` and optimizing your script properly.

Comment: "How do I go about replacing the submit button text with a font awesome icon"

Comment: Oups, sorry. Fixing that now.

Comment: Your IIFE ("self executing function"), makes no difference at all (aside from making `elem` a local variable). Perhaps you meant "put it in a DOM ready handler"? If so, the position in the HTML would not matter.

Comment: Apparently my intention to use an IIFE here was not clear. I have updated the answer.

Comment: I'm afraid that makes even less sense now as it contradicts "However, if you don't have an event listener on DOM load, then you should probably wrap your code in a self-executing function and put it at the end of your HTML". Also, if you want to "optimize your script", just drop the intermediate variable completely (or use a single line of jQuery which would be at least 50% shorter).

Comment: It doesn't contradict with that sentence at all! However, dropping the variable would probably be a better optimization, especially when you consider that it will not be used again. You are right on that one.